# Request for License

Tags: support

Good day,

I am MSc student in Department of Chemistry of the University of Patras and I would like to request your permission in order to include the picture ["Biotage. Left image = microwave heating, right image = oil bath, both taken after 1 min of heating"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/77112/7951) in my Master's Thesis.

Thank you,
Polychronaki Georgia

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/

Answer (score 5):

I'm not 100% sure where that image is taken from. You may be better off taking similar images from other sources:

- https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/debate-over-microwave-boost-to-reactions-rumbles-on/7735.article
- [*Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2004,** *43* (46), 6250–6284](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.200400655) (Fig 1)

and citing the article/webpage according to whatever style you are using.